# Spring Reactive WebFlux reports empty flux when using application/stream+json

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I have a reactive core WebClient to post to a given endpoint. The payload is a flux of JsonNodes and the content-type is `application/stream+json`

```
JsonNode response = localEP.post().uri( "/createItem" )
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
    .body( BodyInserters.fromPublisher(itemData, JsonNode.class ))
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono( JsonNode.class )
    .block();
```

On the server end I have tried both a Spring Controller style and Spring Web Reactive FunctionHandler to process the payload of the above call with a payload that is a Flux.

```
  @PostMapping(path = "/dev/jobad/dynamo", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Flux<JsonNode> loadItems (@RequestBody Flux<JsonNode> items) {
       items.subscribe(storage::add);
       JsonNode response = new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode().put( "shady", "shade" );
      return Flux.just( response );
    }
```

The return to the client is always ok, however the server reports that the content of the flux is empty. If I change `(@RequestBody Flux<JsonNode> items` to `(@RequestBody JsonNode items` The payload is received fine.  The WebClient logs appear to indicate that it has written the data on the wire and processed the response.  However the body seems to empty

```
Reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebInputException: Response status 400 with reason "Request body is missing: public reactor.core.publisher.Flux<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode> com.talroo.rest.JobResource.loadJobs(reactor.core.publisher.Flux<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode>)"
Caused by: org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebInputException: 
Response status 400 with reason "Request body is missing: public 
reactor.core.publisher.Flux<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode>
```

What do I need to do to be able to handle the request body of a post as a Flux?

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think Spring officially supports reading/writing Jackson `JsonNode` instances directly from Controllers. Your application is supposed to ask for a domain object or something like a `Map<String, String>`.

Now in Jackson's model, a `JsonNode` represents any node in the JSON tree - as it is a tree, you can expect to get a `Flux` of nodes, but you are apparently able to get the root node - which explains the behavior you're seeing.

So I think your application should rather rely on higher-level classes and let Jackson deserialize them for you.

Note that your controller implementation is also breaking a few rules:

- you should not call blocking operators, such as `block`, within a method that returns a reactive type (your controller is not breaking this one, but close)
- you should not break the reactive pipeline and decouple the reading of the request and the writing of the response; chances are the HTTP exchange could be closed before your controller has a chance to read the whole request. Calling `subscribe` just does that.

Comment: I've added the item as a domain object and change the controller to :

    public Mono<Void> loadJobs (@RequestBody Flux<Job> jobs) {
    return this.repository.create(jobs);

Where the repository is writes to an ArrayList. The result is the same. Not items are added to the arrraylis

Comment: I can’t answer in comments with bits of code in them. Please ask a new question showing what you’ve got (including the repository implementations

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your responses. I will open a new question with full code and description.

Comment: Wrote a new question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472299/webflux-not-sending-data-when-using-application-streamjson