# WebFlux not sending data when using application/stream+json

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I have a reactive core WebClient to post to a given endpoint. The payload is a flux of `Job` objects and the content-type is application/stream+json
    Flux jobFlux = Flux.just(new Job());

```
Mono<JsonNode> response = localEP.post().uri( "/dev/job" )
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
    .body( BodyInserters.fromObject(jobFlux))
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono( JsonNode.class );
```

On the server end I have tried both a Spring Controller style and Spring Web Reactive FunctionHandler to process the payload of the above call with a payload that is a Flux.

```
  @PostMapping(path = "/dev/job", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.CREATED )
 public Mono<Void> loadJobs (@RequestBody Flux<Job> jobs) {
    return this.repository.create(jobs); 
 }
```

The domain class `Job` creates and id when a new object is instantiated:

```
  public Job() {
    UUID guid = UUID.randomUUID();
    id = guid.toString();
    title = "Random String";
  }
```

The repository currently is just a stub:

```
@Repository
public class DemoJobRepository implements ReactiveRepository<Job> {
   private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoJobRepository.class);
   private final List<Job> jobs = Lists.newArrayList();

@Override
public Mono<Void> create(Publisher<Job> jobStream) {
    return Flux.from(jobStream).doOnNext(jobs::add).then();
}

@Override
public Flux<Job> getAll() {
    return Flux.fromIterable(jobs);
}

@Override
public Mono<Job> findById(String id) {
    return null;
}
}
```

I don't see the client attempting to send the requestbody. We I called `block` on the client to get the result, I see the client send the request, however the server endpoint always sees an empty flux.  Please, any help is very appreciate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Reactive WebFlux reports empty flux when using application/stream+json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459265/spring-reactive-webflux-reports-empty-flux-when-using-application-streamjson)

Comment: From what I understand  I should not "break the reactive pipeline and decouple the reading of the request and the writing of the response; chances are the HTTP exchange could be closed before your controller has a chance to read the whole request. Calling subscribe does just that." 
 Where are you saying to call `subscribe` in the repository?

Comment: Also I'm using the content type of application/stream+json because the intent is to stream data over a connection as oppose to making many individual request

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my intention. The second question of my question is:
    The payload is a flux of Job objects and the content-type is application/stream+json

Thus I don't intend to create multiple request, but rather stream the payload until it is complete.

Comment: You send one object to the server. Streaming makes absolutely no difference. Streaming JSON data means sending objects individually instead of all at once, which can reduce the memory consumption. There is no difference concerning requests.

Comment: Ok, I'll figure out the content type discrepancy. Right now I can't seem to a get the content sent. The other link you referenced as a duplicate was one I created and was told to open this one with Repo info.

Comment: I have retracted my closing vote. You need to subscribe to the response to get the  reques sent, like `.bodyToMono( JsonNode.class ).subscribe(...)`. `block` has the same effect. Instead of `fromObject` try `fromPublisher`.

Comment: @abetteroliver Thank your for your assistance. I really do appreciate it. I've added `subscribe` see below comment:

With no luck. When I use `block` in place of `subscribe` the request is sent.  I would have expected the same for both.

Comment: @abetteroliver that did it. Thank you. I don't see the link to mark correct and give you credit.

Comment: Glad it works now. Which solution did you end up with? `block` and `fromPublisher`?

Comment: Used `fromPublisher`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reactive types, [nothing happens until you subscribe](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactive.subscribe) - building the reactive pipeline will not execute what's it's supposed to do, only subscribing to it will start the process.

There are several ways to subscribe:

- calling any of the `subscribe` variants. Many of them take lambdas as parameters that are executed when the processing is done, or ended with an error. Using the empty variant is a bit risky because it just launches the execution but you get no callback whatsoever. Technically, nothing is waiting on it so the JVM could exit before the processing is done
- calling any of the `block`/`collect` methods. This not only subscribes but also returns the expected value(s).

  Both of those choices should never be done within a method that returns a reactive type, otherwise this will lead to serious problems in your application.

Comment: No. Calling `retrieve` does send the request and asks for the response body - but since it returns a reactive type, nothing happens until subscription time.